# Comparison on Hive, Impala, HBASE and SQL for "order by"

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hbase, impala

I am totally new to hive, impala, HBASE. I am doing some full text search application. I got a painful step of sorting the relevance using order by in SQL on oracle platform. Wonder if I change it in the hadoop ecosystem would help or not. Wish someone can help with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use full text search in Hadoop you should consider using [Apache Solr](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/searching-data-solr/) ([Cloudera Search](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cdh/search.html) if you use Cloudera)

Comment: Thanks, Santiago. Have you done full text search against Solr. If so, how large is the database and what's the efficiency like in Solor?

Comment: I've used solr with Cloudera and works pretty well. We're talking about a 100s Gb dataset. The main gotcha is that you need to reindex when the schema changes.